# Mysqlclient and PyPy on Windows

Tags: mysql-python, pypy

I spent hours to try to install mysqlclient with PyPy3.6 v7.3.0 on Windows 10, my main problem is that the MySQL Connector C 6.1 is in 64b and PyPy is on 32b.

My last hope if is someone have a compiled wheel for PyPy3.6 v7.3.0, there is no version available on Christoph Gohlke page : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Thank you

Comment: Here you go: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient